# Speech-to-text api polling timeout with LRO files on google cloud storage

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I am trying to transcribe audio files (.wav) with an average duration of 20/30 minutes but google bees after exactly 4 minutes and 30 seconds delete the task. I have looked in their documentation and a reference is made to a polling algorithm with a duration of 24 hours, moreover when the error is received, this github link is given to better understand the problem : https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java?tab=readme-ov-file#lro-timeouts

I have overwritten the polling algorithm but it seems that it is not applied correctly. The file is successfully loaded into the bucket and the URI is also successfully obtained.

```
import com.google.api.gax.core.CredentialsProvider;
import com.google.api.gax.core.FixedCredentialsProvider;
import com.google.api.gax.longrunning.OperationFuture;
import com.google.api.gax.longrunning.OperationTimedPollAlgorithm;
import com.google.api.gax.retrying.RetrySettings;
import com.google.api.gax.retrying.TimedRetryAlgorithm;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.*;

import com.google.cloud.storage.BlobId;
import com.google.cloud.storage.BlobInfo;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage;
import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions;
import org.threeten.bp.Duration;


import java.io.*;


import java.nio.file.Paths;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class Main {

    private static String textFileName = "";
    private static String textFilePath = "";
    private static final String AUDIO_ENCODING_LINEAR16 = "LINEAR16";
    private static RecognitionConfig config;
    private static String comune = "porco";
    private static String linguaTraduzione = "it-IT";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            performAudioConversionAndTranscription(new File("C:\\Users\\aless\\IdeaProjects\\google\\src\\main\\java\\org\\example\\sa.json"),"C:\\Users\\aless\\Downloads\\prova.wav");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

    private static void performAudioConversionAndTranscription(File credenziali, String audioPath) {

        try {

            //--------------------CONFIGURAZIONE E CREAZIONE CREDENZIALI STT------------------------//
            GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(credenziali));
            CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = FixedCredentialsProvider.create(googleCredentials);
            SpeechSettings settings = SpeechSettings.newBuilder().setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();
            SpeechClient speechClient = SpeechClient.create(settings);



            //----------------------SET CONFIGURAZIONE POLLING------------------------------//
            SpeechSettings.Builder speechSettings = SpeechSettings.newBuilder();
            TimedRetryAlgorithm timedRetryAlgorithm =
                    OperationTimedPollAlgorithm.create(
                            RetrySettings.newBuilder()
                                    .setInitialRetryDelay(Duration.ofMillis(500L))
                                    .setRetryDelayMultiplier(1.5)
                                    .setMaxRetryDelay(Duration.ofMillis(5000L))
                                    .setTotalTimeout(Duration.ofHours(24L)) // set polling timeout to 24 hours
                                    .build());



            speechSettings.longRunningRecognizeOperationSettings().setPollingAlgorithm(timedRetryAlgorithm);

            //----------------CONFIGURAZIONE OGGETTO PER LA DIARIZZAZIONE----------------------//
            SpeakerDiarizationConfig speakerDiarizationConfig = SpeakerDiarizationConfig.newBuilder()
                    .setEnableSpeakerDiarization(true)
                    .setMinSpeakerCount(1)
                    .setMaxSpeakerCount(6)
                    .build();

            String audioFileName = "rdfd";


            //----------------------------CONFIGURAZIONE STT---------------------------//
            config = RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
                    .setEncoding(RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.valueOf(AUDIO_ENCODING_LINEAR16))
                    .setLanguageCode(linguaTraduzione)
                    .setDiarizationConfig(speakerDiarizationConfig)
                    .setEnableAutomaticPunctuation(true)
                    .setEnableWordConfidence(true)
                    .setAudioChannelCount(2)
                    .build();

            textFileName = audioFileName + "_TRASCRIZIONE_.txt";
            String audioFolderPath = new File(audioPath).getParent();
            textFilePath = "C:\\Users\\aless\\Downloads\\" + textFileName;
            System.out.println(textFilePath);
            Storage storage =  StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(googleCredentials).build().getService();

            // Verifica se la cartella esiste già
            if (storage.get("cartabia", comune) == null) {
                // Crea l'oggetto BlobInfo per la cartella
                BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder("cartabia", comune + "/").build();

                // Carica l'oggetto BlobInfo nel bucket
                storage.create(blobInfo);
            }

            //------------------------CARTELLA CREATA--------------------//
            String fileName = new File(audioPath).getName();

            // Rimuovi l'estensione .wav se presente
            if (fileName.endsWith(".wav")) {
                fileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.length() - 4);
            }

            // Aggiungi _comune.wav alla fine del nome del file
            fileName = fileName + "_" + comune + ".wav";

            // Costruisci il percorso completo del file nella cartella
            String fullPath = comune + "/" + fileName;
            System.out.println(fullPath);
            // Crea l'oggetto BlobId con il percorso completo
            BlobId blobId = BlobId.of("cartabia", fullPath);

            // Crea l'oggetto BlobInfo con l'ID del blob
            BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).build();

            //---------------EVITA RACE CONDITION---------------------//
            Storage.BlobWriteOption precondition;
            if (storage.get("cartabia", fullPath) == null) {
                precondition = Storage.BlobWriteOption.doesNotExist();
            } else {
                precondition =
                        Storage.BlobWriteOption.generationMatch(
                        );
            }

            //--------------CARICA FILE WAV NEL BUCKET-----------------//
            storage.createFrom(blobInfo, Paths.get(audioPath), precondition);

            //---------------OTTIENE URI ASSOCIATA AL WAV APPENA CARICATO-------------------//
            String gcsUri = String.format("gs://cartabia/%s",fullPath);

            System.out.println(gcsUri);

            RecognitionAudio audio = RecognitionAudio.newBuilder().setUri(gcsUri).build();


            OperationFuture<LongRunningRecognizeResponse, LongRunningRecognizeMetadata> response =
                    speechClient.longRunningRecognizeAsync(config, audio);

           while(!response.isDone()){
               Thread.sleep(10000);
           }

            System.out.println(response.get());
            List<SpeechRecognitionResult> resultaa = response.get().getResultsList();
```